# setTimeout(number) cause breaking node.js REPL

Tags: javascript, node.js, read-eval-print-loop

For example, when I write in node.js REPL in terminal:

```
setTimeout(3);
```

it shows me this error:

```
timers.js:110
    first._onTimeout();
          ^
TypeError: Property '_onTimeout' of object [object Object] is not a function
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
```

but, what is interesting it breaks the whole session (instead just throwing the error).

Why is this happening?

Thanks.

**PS: I know I should add function as first parameter. Just wanted to know why it breaks the session.**

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. The session runs normally after throwing the error for me.

Comment: check this: http://postimg.org/image/qxwdv5qsr/full/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `setTimeout` or `setImmediate`, it adds your `callback` to to the event queue since Node can't guarantee that your callback will be fired exactly in `n`. Since `3` isn't a function it fails to fire, raises an exception and exits before it's finished returning to your execution scope which is why it will kill the REPL.

Now, that's different to supplying a callback and an error occurring there since the callback will be defined in the execution scope of the calling script. If your callback is to throw an error, it will raise the exception in the right scope. Note that Node doesn't support a string for the callback arg like most browsers do.

For such a low timeout you're better off using `process.nextTick(callback)` which is much better for perf and security but you'll still see an error raised at top level.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
    setTimeout(function() {
     console.log('This runs every minute');
    }, 60000);
```

Like Dave said, setTimeout expects a function. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: I know, just wanted to know, why it breaks the session instead of just returning error.